# React HOC, instanceof, wrapped with?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I use HOC and the compose method from Redux to wrap a component in components. A simple example :

```
const Textinput = class Textinput extends Component {
   ...
}

export default compose(
  Theme,
  Validator,
)(Textinput);
```

The result rendered by react is :

```
<theme>
  <validator>
    <textinput />
```

Imagine another component with this children :

```
<Textinput />
<span>Test</span>
<Select />
<br/>
```

Textinput and Select are wrapped in the Theme/Validator components with HOC. I want to enumerate each element in this component :

```
const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {

}
```

But :

1. how to know if a rendered element is wrapped in a specific component (like Validator or Theme) ?
2. how to know if the component behind an element is an instanceof Select or Textinput (and not Theme) ?

Comment: If you control the HOCs, you can pass that information down as props too. Also, have you tried inspecting the `displayName` property of the children?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add a new property on each HOC object like :

```
Theme.innerInstances = {
  instance: WrappedComponent,
  innerInstances: WrappedComponent.innerInstances,
};

Validator.innerInstances = {
  instance: WrappedComponent,
  innerInstances: WrappedComponent.innerInstances,
};
```